# SingleOrDefault() throws an exception on more than one element

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, collections

I'm getting an exception whenever I fetch like this

```
Feature f = o.Features.SingleOrDefault(e => e.LinkName == PageLink);
```

because this can return one or more than one element. What is the alternative approach that I can use to solve this issue?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`Single` and `SingleOrDefault` are designed to throw if more that one match exists in the sequence. A consequence of this is that the entire sequence must be iterated prior to completion. It does not sound like this is what you want. Try `FirstOrDefault` instead:

```
Feature f = o.Features
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.vcr_LinkName == PageLink && e.bit_Activate == true);
```

This will (generally) perform better because it completes as soon as a match is found.

Of course, if you actually want to retain more than one element, a `Where` clause would be more appropriate:

```
IEnumerable<Feature> fs = o.Features
    .Where(e => e.vcr_LinkName == PageLink && e.bit_Activate == true);
```

Answer (score 34):

Alternatively, if you only want the item when there is exactly one match and do not want to throw when there are more than one, this can be easily accomplished. I've created an extension method for this in my project:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static TSource SingleWhenOnly<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        var results = source.Take(2).ToArray();

        return results.Length == 1 ? results[0] : default(TSource);
    }

    public static TSource SingleWhenOnly<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (predicate == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");

        var results = source.Where(predicate).Take(2).ToArray();

        return results.Length == 1 ? results[0] : default(TSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm using this currently. I renamed it to `ExclusiveOrDefault` and also made an extension method `Exclusive` that throws an error when there are *zero* elements, but returns null when there are *2 or more* elements.

Answer (score 16):

If you only want the *first* element, use `FirstOrDefault` instead.

Basically, here are the options in terms of valid results (i.e. where you don't want to throw) and what to use:

- Exactly one: `Single`
- One or zero: `SingleOrDefault`
- One or more: `First`
- Zero or more: `FirstOrDefault`

(`ElementAt` and `ElementAtOrDefault`, `Last` and `LastOrDefault` are also available.)

Answer (score 8):

I've found I need the behavior of returning a default value if there is not exactly one element (i.e. zero, two, or more) more often than I need the normal `SingleOrDefault` behavior, so here's my adapted version of [Pieter van Ginkel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185067/singleordefault-throw-exception-on-more-than-one-element/10552139#10552139):

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty or contains more than one element.
    /// </summary>
    public static TSource SingleOrDefaultIfMultiple<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        var elements = source.Take(2).ToArray();

        return (elements.Length == 1) ? elements[0] : default(TSource);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty or contains more than one element.
    /// </summary>
    public static TSource SingleOrDefaultIfMultiple<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source.Where(predicate).SingleOrDefaultIfMultiple();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty or contains more than one element.
    /// </summary>
    public static TSource SingleOrDefaultIfMultiple<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
    {
        var elements = source.Take(2).ToArray();

        return (elements.Length == 1) ? elements[0] : default(TSource);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty or contains more than one element.
    /// </summary>
    public static TSource SingleOrDefaultIfMultiple<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return source.Where(predicate).SingleOrDefaultIfMultiple();
    }
}
```

I've omitted the null argument checks because I'm OK with relying on the `Take` and `Where` calls to throw exceptions when the arguments are null, but you might feel otherwise.

Comment: Nice. I have renamed the lengthy SingleOrDefaultIfMultiple() to OnlyOrDefault() though. Your comments does even suggest so....

Comment: Or, what about "TheOneOrDefault" (I recently rewatched "The Matrix" trilogy) hehe....

Comment: @Marcel I do like `OnlyOrDefault()`, but part of my reason for the longer name is so it would come up as an intellisense option when I (or other team members) start typing `.SingleOrDefault` and we hopefully end up picking the one that's appropriate for the situation.

Answer (score 4):

`SingleOrDefault` suggests that you are expecting 0 or 1 results from your query. If you have more than 1 then there is something wrong with your data or query.

If you are expecting more than 1 result and only want the first one, then `FirstOrDefault` should be used.

Answer (score 2):

`Single` means that you expect be one element in the sequence.
`SingleOrDefault` means that you expect there to be one or zero elements in the sequence.
This should be used when you want know there is one (or zero) and you want it to crash when more than one it returned.

If you are after just one, use `First` (or `FirstOrDefault`) as suggested above, but make sure you order the data correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx) if the condition satisfy more than result it will throw error.

you can achieve your result by using [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx)