# Have a JsonConverter that is only used during deserialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.text.json

My goal is to deserialize this JSON into a `Dictionary<string, TValue>`.

```
[
  {
    "key": "foo",
    "value": 42
  }
]
```

My approach is a custom `JsonConverter<Dictionary<string, TValue>>` with an appropriate `JsonConverterFactory`.

Deserialization is working fine, but I'm struggling with the serialization part. During serialization, I want this to be serialized like any other dictionary, so the result from serializing the same value as above should be

```
{
  "foo": 42
}
```

My idea was to just pass it down to the default `JsonDictionaryConverter<TDictionary, TKey, TValue>`.
This is my Write method:

```
public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Dictionary<string, TValue> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    var newOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
    newOptions.Converters.Remove(this);
    JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, newOptions);
}
```

However I always get a NullReferenceException in `JsonDictionaryConverter<TDictionary, TKey, TValue>OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TDictionary dictionary, JsonSerializerOptions options, ref WriteStack state)`.
The Exception happens here (Line 299), because `state.Current.JsonTypeInfo.ElementTypeInfo` is `null`.

```
state.Current.DeclaredJsonPropertyInfo = state.Current.JsonTypeInfo.ElementTypeInfo!.PropertyInfoForTypeInfo;
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can just skip my converter during serialization or have this Exception go away?

Comment: System.Text.Json has no equivalent to Json.NET's `JsonConverter.CanWrite`.  For one workaround, see [How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65430420/3744182).

Comment: I'm doing exactly what is described in the linked answer (remove my converter from the options und use the default serialization). However that gives me the mentioned Exception.

Comment: Are you using compile-time source generation?  Can you share a [mcve], as well as the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any?

Comment: As an alternative you might use custom `JsonSerializerOptions` for your model formatter for this specific controller.  See [Change the JSON serialization settings of a single ASP.NET Core controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52623772/3744182).

Comment: Your code does seem a little different than the code from [How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430421/3744182), You are removing the inner `JsonConverter<T>` from the options list like so: `newOptions.Converters.Remove(this);`.  The answer there removes the factory, not the inner converter.  Maybe that accounts for the difference?  A [mcve] would clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

Following *[How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430421/3744182)*, you are trying to generate a default serialization by copying the current `JsonSerializerOptions` and removing the current converter from its converters list.  Your problem seems to be here:

> ```
> newOptions.Converters.Remove(this);
> ```

You are using the [factory converter pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#sample-factory-pattern-converter), and this line removes the **inner, nested `JsonDictionaryConverter<TDictionary, TKey, TValue>`** from `newOptions.Converters`.  However, you need to remove the **outer factory** from the converters list, not the inner generated converter, as it is the factory that was added into the converters list previously.

The following is a working `JsonConverterFactory` that deserializes any `IDictionary<string, TValue>` that might be an array.  When re-serializing, it removes itself from the converter list which results in default serialization:

```
public class JsonDictionaryConverterFactory : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => TryGetDictionaryType(typeToConvert, out _, out _, out  _);
    
    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        TryGetDictionaryType(typeToConvert, out var dictionaryType, out var keyType, out var valueType);        
        var converterType = typeof(JsonDictionaryConverter<,,>).MakeGenericType(dictionaryType, keyType, valueType);
        return (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(converterType, options, this);
    }
    
    static bool TryGetDictionaryType(Type typeToConvert, out Type dictionaryType, out Type keyType, out Type valueType)
    {
        var keyValueTypes = typeToConvert.GetDictionaryKeyValueType();
        if (keyValueTypes != null && keyValueTypes.Length == 2)
        {
            // Todo; maybe put a restriction here on keyType, such as keyType == typeof(string).
            if (typeToConvert.IsInterface)
            {
                var concreteType = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(keyValueTypes);
                if (typeToConvert.IsAssignableFrom(concreteType))
                {
                    dictionaryType = concreteType;
                    keyType = keyValueTypes[0];
                    valueType = keyValueTypes[1];
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (typeToConvert.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
                {
                    dictionaryType = typeToConvert;
                    keyType = keyValueTypes[0];
                    valueType = keyValueTypes[1];
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        dictionaryType = keyType = valueType = null;
        return false;
    }

    class JsonDictionaryConverter<TDictionary, TKey, TValue> : JsonConverter<TDictionary> where TDictionary : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, new()
    {
        readonly JsonSerializerOptions modifiedOptions;
        
        public JsonDictionaryConverter(JsonSerializerOptions options, JsonDictionaryConverterFactory factory) => this.modifiedOptions = options.CopyAndRemoveConverter(factory.GetType());
    
        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TDictionary value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>  JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, modifiedOptions);
            
        public override TDictionary Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonTokenType.StartObject:
                    return (TDictionary)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, typeToConvert, modifiedOptions);
                case JsonTokenType.StartArray:
                    var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>>(ref reader, modifiedOptions);
                    var dictionary = new TDictionary();
                    foreach (var item in list)
                        dictionary.Add(item);
                    return dictionary;
                default:
                    throw new JsonException();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonSerializerOptions CopyAndRemoveConverter(this JsonSerializerOptions options, Type converterType)
    {
        var copy = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
        for (var i = copy.Converters.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (copy.Converters[i].GetType() == converterType)
                copy.Converters.RemoveAt(i);
        return copy;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfacesAndSelf(this Type type)
        => (type ?? throw new ArgumentNullException()).IsInterface ? new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces()) : type.GetInterfaces();

    public static IEnumerable<Type []> GetDictionaryKeyValueTypes(this Type type)
        => type.GetInterfacesAndSelf().Where(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>)).Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments());

    public static Type [] GetDictionaryKeyValueType(this Type type)
        => type.GetDictionaryKeyValueTypes().SingleOrDefaultIfMultiple();

    // Copied from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25319572
    // By https://stackoverflow.com/users/3542863/sean-rose
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185067/singleordefault-throws-an-exception-on-more-than-one-element
    public static TSource SingleOrDefaultIfMultiple<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        var elements = source.Take(2).ToArray();
        return (elements.Length == 1) ? elements[0] : default(TSource);
    }
}
```

And then add to options as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new JsonDictionaryConverterFactory() },
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
};
```

Notes:

- I set `PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase` because your `"key"` and `"value"` property names are camel cased.  If you do not want to use camel case globally, inside `ReadJson()` you may wish to deserialize to a `List<KeyValueDTO>` (such as the one shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59652323/3744182) to *[System.Text.Json Serialize dictionary as array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59644016/3744182)*) with explicitly camel-cased property names, rather than to a `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.
- You may want to add some restrictions in `TryGetDictionaryType()` on the key type, e.g. to only allow `string` type keys.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/frAwmI).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using helper class and `ToDictionary`.

```
var json = @"[
    {
      ""key"": ""foo"",
      ""value"": 42
    }
  ]";

var o = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Z>>(json, new JsonSerializerOptions { IncludeFields = true});
var d = o!.ToDictionary( x => x.key, x => x.value);

Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(d, new JsonSerializerOptions {WriteIndented = true, IncludeFields = true}));

class Z { public string? key {get;set; } public int? value {get; set;} }
```

This prints

```
{
  "foo": 42
}
```

Comment: The serializer must deserialize values which are coming in as a POST body. Because of that it should be registered in the global Converters, used by the ASP.Net Core pipeline and automatically selected if the model is a Dictionary or contains a Dictionary.

Comment: Use List<Z> on your input type and Dict on your output type. I'd say it is correct to use different input and output types if they look different.

Answer (score -2):

**You May Refer I Use JSON convert for convert datatable to JSON format**

```csharp
public static DataTable JsonToDataTable(string Json)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json, (typeof(DataTable)));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string chk = ex.Message;
                dt = new DataTable();
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The querent is using System.Text.Json not Json.NET, and is deserializing a dictionary, not a data table. I also don't recommend swallowing and ignoring all exceptions.